# privilege for user in sql

Tags: mysql, admin

I just create mysql 8.0.20 server on AWS RDS.
I'm try to change global varible.. on workbench or via the terminal..
and get this msg

```
 Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

but I have only one master user..

```
mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| admin            | %         |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| rdsadmin         | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.16 sec)
```

I'm confused and don't understand who is the master.. (according to aws is admin)
I want to understand with which user I can add another or run some simple script like

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5000;
```

Comment: Show `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;` output.

Comment: but how I add grants for this user?
I have only one master user and he doesn't have all the grant..

Comment: If you have none user with SUPER privilege then use lost MySQL password recovery procedure (--skip-grant-tables) and create a user with SUPER privilege or grant this privilege to some existing user.